# Undecidable problems involving elementary functions

Tags: logic, computational-complexity, elementary-functions

I am reading the article "Some undecidable problems involving elementary functions of a real variable" by Daniel Richardson and have some problems with understanding Lemma Three :

Let $h(w)=w\sin w, g(w)=w\sin w^3$. For any $x_1$ and $x_2$ and any $\delta>0$, there is a $w\gt 0$ so  that
$|h(w)-x_1|< \delta$, $g(w)=x_2$

Proof :

Let $w_2$ and $w_1$ be two numbers such that

$w_2>w_1>|x_2|$,

$h(w_2)=x_1$,

$w_2^3-w_1^3>2\pi$,

$(w_2-w_1)(w_2+1)<\delta$.

Since $w_2$ and $w_1$ are greater that $|x_2|$ and since $w_2^3-w_1^3>2\pi$, there is a number $w$ between $w_1$ and $w_2$ so that  $g(w)=x_2$

We want to show that $|h(w)-x_1|<\delta$

$|h(w)-x_1|=|h(w)-h(w_2)|$

$\leq (w_2-w_1)|\sin x+x\cos x|$ for some x between $w_1$ and $w_2$

$<(w_2-w_1)(w_2+1)$

$<\delta$

I am confused about this line $|h(w)-x_1|=|h(w)-h(w_2)|\leq (w_2-w_1)|\sin  x+x\cos x|$

The real question is why we have $\leq (w_2-w_1)|\sin x+x\cos x|$ here? How did we get $|\sin x+x\cos x|$? Is it obtained by using mean value theorem? Can somebody explain, please?

Comment: my mistake( - edited "We want to show that $|h(w)-x_1|<\delta$"

Comment: since when $\epsilon \to 0$ : $\sin (\pi n+\epsilon) \sim \epsilon (-1)^n$, write $\omega = \pi n + \epsilon$, hence,  when $\epsilon \to 0$ : $w \sin w^3 \sim (\pi n+\epsilon) \epsilon^3  (-1)^n $ and $w \sin w \sim (\pi n+\epsilon)\epsilon (-1)^n$.